# How do I calculate CPU usage per process in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm no computer scientist but I think every process in Javascript uses some CPU power.
I'm aware that when we store a variable, some memory of the device is occupied/used to hold the value and its name. but what I need to know is how much CPU was used to store that varible and what is the unit of measurement? (metric if possible).
Just storing the variable is not all is looking for, I'm talking about everything right from calling a method, math, XMLHttpRequests, loops, timeouts. , etc.
eg:

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 100;
var state = "loading";
// var xyz = null;
console.log(x+","+y+","+state);
```

Now according to my previous description this code should take more than 5 cpu powers to execute, "cpu powers" being the unit of measurement.

Comment: The CPU does not provide storage, it provides processing power. Storage (ephemeral or long-term) happens elsewhere in hardware (RAM, SDD/HDD, etc.) Can you elaborate on why you need access to this information from JavaScript? This is usually not something that’s exposed by browsers to a JavaScript engine as it can have some security implications regarding unwanted profiling of end users. Besides, JavaScript is so heavily abstracted that anything even remotely close to this level should  be handled elsewhere in the stack *for* you.

Comment: @esqew I think OP is asking how many clock cycles each storage/operator/retreival takes ?

Comment: Your JavaScript becomes byte code that is JIT compiled.  The efficiency of the compiled result depends on the JavaScript engine in use and the architecture being targeted.  Most people measure time.  For example, measure it with https://jsbench.me/

Comment: The raw measurement of CPU is cycles - a cycle is one beat of a MHz. So a CPU running at 4GHz has the "power" of 4 billion cycles each second. Normally though, we'd just measure time. Roughly speaking how much time a program takes to do something is how much "CPU" it uses.

Answer (score 3):

#### You are asking for how much CPU time the steps take

This is called profiling. It tells you how demanding each step of a program is.

An easy way to approach this is the profiler built in to Chrome:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/

It gives you a display like this showing you which lines of code consume more CPU resource.

[image]